# WordPress term link filter

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have to append a string on term link, actually i have this structure :

```
domain.com/term_1/sub_term_1
```

I want to append something after 'sub_term_1' like this :

```
domain.com/term_1/sub_term_1/my_custom_text
```

So i think this should do the trick :

```
add_filter('term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3);
function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    return $url . '/mu_custom_text';  
}
```

Now **get_term_link(term_id, 'taxonomy_slug')** returns the right url i want, but redirects to 404 error page.

Please help, my aim is to append a custom string anywhere in term link? i'm lost and googled till yesterday but no success.

**NB : custom text is dynamic, inside a sesssion, so appending from dashboard is not possible**

======== UPDATE ========
I found a solution:

**First i created custom rewrite**

```
function create_new_url_querystring() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'category/(.+?)/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&custom_string=$matches[2]','top'
    );

}

add_action('init', 'create_new_url_querystring');
```

**Secondo i append a string from term url**

```
add_filter('term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3);
function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {

    if( $taxonomy == 'product_cat' ) {
        return $url.'/'.custom_string;
    } 

    return $url;

}
```

So this url is working :

```
domain.com/term_1/sub_term_1/my_custom_text
```

And this too : 
    domain.com/term_1/sub_term_1/sub_term_two/my_custom_text

But now i got another issue for more than one 'sub_term', my navigation menu is not appearing. If i have only one sub_term on url the menu appears.

Thank you.

Comment: try by pre-pending custom text in `Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks` under `Optional section` (for taxonomy). reference: [How to Add ‘/blog/’ Prefix in Blog Posts](http://www.webhat.in/article/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-add-blog-prefix-in-blog-posts/).

Comment: Hey thank, you for your response, yes append from dashboard is working, but how if this custom text is dynamic? i mean inside a session.

Comment: right now I don't know how to do that but let me try that, once I'll find the solution will post the solution.